# Installing the Python package numba using Conda is running into conflicts

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to install Numba on my fresh Linux machine. I've tried **conda and pip**, essentially the error is the same. I'm using Python 3.7 (aligned to legacy code I'm trying update). This is what I'm seeing (taken from `conda install numba`):

```
(sensaas) anthony@mechanicus:~/sensaas$ conda install numba
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - <unknown>/win-64::open3d==0.12.0=py37_0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                                                                                                                                             failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (numpy):

  - numba -> numpy[version='1.13.*|>=1.10,<1.11.0a0|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.18,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.23|>=1.18,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.24|>=1.19,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.24|>=1.21,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.25|>=1.23,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.25|>=1.21,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.24|>=1.21,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.23|>=1.19,!=1.22.0,!=1.22.1,!=1.22.2,<1.23|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|>=1.12,<1.13.0a0|>=1.14,<1.15.0a0|>=1.13,<1.14.0a0|>=1.11,<1.12.0a0']

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package six conflicts for:
numba -> singledispatch -> six
numpy -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> six
numpy-base -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> six
mkl_random -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> six
mkl-service -> six
mkl_fft -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> six
six
```

As mentioned, Python is 3.7, pip is 22.3.1, and Conda is 23.9.0. There is mentioned a reference to open3d, version 0.12.0 - that must remain that version (and hence tied to Python 3.7).

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.